# How to solve this problem about discrete mathematics (Probability)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Number of ways of spelling Abracadabra in this grid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40772/number-of-ways-of-spelling-abracadabra-in-this-grid)

Determine the number of ways of spelling “mathematics” in the array below by following a path from top to bottom in which each letter is directly below, and just to the right or left of the previous letter.

```
                              M
                         A        A
                     T        T        T
                H        H        H        H
            E        E        E        E        E
       M        M        M        M        M        M
            A        A        A        A        A
                T        T        T        T
                     I        I        I
                         C        C
                              S
```

Comment: Your question is identical to the linked question, except for the letters involved, so the answer to your question is the same: 252.