# How many routes are there through from top left corner to top right in a 20x20 grid? Binomial Coefficent explanation

Tags: binomial-coefficients, project-euler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Counting number of moves on a grid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12093/counting-number-of-moves-on-a-grid)

I'm trying to solve this computer programming problem on Project Euler: http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=15

> Starting in the top left corner of a $2\times2$ grid, there are 6 routes
>   (without backtracking) to the bottom right corner.
>
> How many routes are there through a $20\times20$ grid?

I've seen a solution using nCr, where n = 40 and r = 20.

Could someone explain to me how this work, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Consider the general problem of the number of paths in a rectangular grid $m\times n$. Call $P(m,n)$ this number.

You should be able to figure out a formula for $P(m,n)$ observing that $P(1,n)=P(m,1)=1$ and $P(m,n)=P(m-1,n)+P(m,n-1)$ when both $m$ and $n$ are $>1$.

Comment: The same hint in different language: Tilt the rectangles/squares 45 degrees, so that the (1,1) position is at the top. Do you see Pascal's triangle forming?