# How many up-or-to-the-right paths from $(0,0)$ to $(8,5)$, and related questions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Recall that in the section on functions, we created an encoding for the paths
from the point $(0, 0)$ to the point $(m, n)$ which either went right or up at each
step. In particular, we said that each path can be represented as a bit string of
length $m+ n$ with exactly $m$ 0's and $n$ 1's.

For this problem, let $m = 8, n = 5$.

a. How many paths are there from $(0, 0)$ to $(8, 5)$?

b. How many of these paths go through the point $(3, 3)$?

c. How many of them avoid the point $(3, 3)$?

Comment: Unless I miss my guess, you have copied out a problem from some source without attribution, which constitutes plagiarism. Please let us know where this problem comes from; why it's worth working on; what progress you have made on it.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12093/counting-number-of-moves-on-a-grid?rq=1

Comment: I got this question from one of my university professor website. the univ is UWM. I have a Qualifying  exam this September and I am solving as much as I can from Discrete mathematics. the source is :

Comment: http://www.cs.uwm.edu/classes/cs317/

Comment: These things are called [Dyck paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_path#Applications_in_combinatorics).

Comment: @Raphael: Not quite, since here there's no restriction about staying below the diagonal.

Comment: @HansLundmark: True, my mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

a. How many ways are there of arranging eight $0$s and five $1$s in a string?

b. How many ways are there of arranging three $0$s and three $1$s in a string? How many ways are there of arranging five $0$s and two $1$s in a string? How many ways are there of arranging three $0$s and three $1$s followed by five $0$s and two $1$s?

c. How is this related to a and b?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend googling the Binomial theorem, as it's an introduction to binomial coefficients. Going from (0,0) to (m,n) is one of the basics of probability. The answer to your question is; $\frac {n!} {k!*(n-k)!}$; n choose k

[image]

n in this case would be te sum of the lines needed to make a path; m+n,
and k would be either horizontal of vertical, so m or n

$\frac {n!} {k!*(n-k)!}$ becomes $\frac {(m+n)!} {m!*n!}$

For things like "going through (3,3)", you could use m = 3, n = 3 to go to (3,3) and multiply that by "going from (3,3) to (8-3, 5-3)", which is the same as using $\frac {(m+n)!} {m!*n!}$ again with m = 8-3, n = 5-3

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, before I added MathJax, it was (m+n)!, I must have accidentally deleted it.