# A question for undergrad Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Imagine a piece of graph paper. Starting at the origin draw a path to the
point (10, 10), that stays on the grid lines (which are one unit apart) and
has a total length of 20. For example, one path is to go from (0, 0) to (0, 7)
to (4, 7) to (4, 10) to (10, 10). Another path goes from (0, 0) to (10, 0) to
(10, 10). How many possible different paths are there?

Comment: Do we have to restrict the paths such that there are no detours? Because if we can make detours, basically we have an infinite number of possible paths. :)

Comment: @RoycePacibe  The path length is 20, so detours won't be possible.  Gorthi, try it for smaller grids.  3x3 and 4x4, say.

Comment: The condition that the total length of the path is equal to 20, restricts the route.

Comment: Ohh yeah, so all we can do is either move up or move right, right? So we don't run out of steps. :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176641  seems to be the same question.

Comment: Yeah, indeed it is. Read there that they call these Dyck paths. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DyckPath.html

Comment: Thank you for the heads up @B.Goddard

Comment: Dyck paths as mentioned by @RoycePacibe are more particular than what you are investigating.  Dyck paths are very specifically those lattice paths who never cross the diagonal (*and begin with a right*) and are related to the Catalan Numbers.  What you are looking at are in fact what falls under the broader description of [*lattice paths*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_path).

Comment: Dyck? @JMoravitz?

Comment: Yes... as in [Walther Von Dyck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walther_von_Dyck).  What?  Is there something about his name that you find surprising?

Comment: Oh... Thank you

Comment: One technique - useful with irregular shapes is to take the lattice and put a $1$ at the start point. Then take the first step and put a $1$ at the points you get to. On the second and further steps you should add the numbers from the points at the beginning of the steps to get the number of ways of getting to each point. [Easier to do than to describe]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many up-or-to-the-right paths from $(0,0)$ to $(8,5)$, and related questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176641/how-many-up-or-to-the-right-paths-from-0-0-to-8-5-and-related-questions)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can move only one unit right or one unit up (but not both) at each step, there  are $$\binom{m+n}{n}=\frac{(m+n)!}{m!\cdot n!}$$ paths from $(0,0)$ to $(m,n).$ This is because this is the number of permutations of $m$ copies of $R$ and $n$ copies of $U.$ So the answer here is $\binom{20}{10}=184756.$

In fact, no left or down moves are possible because more than $m+n$ steps would be needed (at least $m$ steps right and $n$ steps are required no matter what). So the answer holds.

Answer (score 0):

Because not more than $20$ steps can be taken and at least $20$ are needed every step must bring us closer to the endpoint. That means that every step must go up or to the right.

Then from the total $20$ steps we must select $10$ to be steps upwards.

There are: $$\binom{20}{10}$$ ways to select $10$ from $20$ steps.