# Figuring how many paths are there to get to a point on a cartesian coordinate system

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Counting number of moves on a grid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12093/counting-number-of-moves-on-a-grid)

I have an exercise in my Computer Science class, to figure out how many paths there are from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$ on a cartesian coordinate system, while **the only legal moves are `move up` and `move right`**.

Is there a simple method to calculate the number of available paths?

Comment: yes they are, edited.

Comment: Note that ${x + y} \choose x$ = ${x + y}\choose y$

Comment: This is very similar to PE 15 (FYI)... http://projecteuler.net/problem=15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. You must go right $x$ times and up $y$ times, and you may make these $x+y$ moves in any order. Write R for a right move and U for an up move: you want the number of strings of $x$ R’s and $y$ U’s. There are $\binom{x+y}x$ ways to choose which $x$ places get the R’s, and that completely determines the string, so the answer is $\binom{x+y}x$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $x\ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$ you will make $x+y$ moves in total and among these are $y$ moves up. That should be $x+y\choose y$.

Comment: @amWhy Of course, thanks