# Confused on logic behind number of paths from (0,0) to (m,n)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I saw on multiple threads like this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12093/counting-number-of-moves-on-a-grid?rq=1)

that to calculate the number of paths, you essentially do n+m choose m or n+m choose n. But I'm kinda confused. Why just choose m or n? Cant it be m+n choose n + m+n choose m ?Don't we need at least m+n moves, since each move either goes up one or right one?

Comment: Once you decide which are the horizontal steps, the others are the vertical steps.

Comment: And we need **exactly** $m+n$ steps, $m$ to the right and $n$ up.

Comment: I would recommend testing it out for some explicit, small values of m and n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process terminates after exactly $m + n$ steps, no matter what the order of the right/up movements are. However, you need to choose $m$ of these $m + n$ movements to be movements to the right, which is where we obtain ${m+n\choose m}$. Likewise, we could choose $n$ of the steps to be upwards, which yields ${m + n\choose n}$, an equivalent expression.

Comment: thank you! just wondering, what would we calculate to find number of paths without crossing y = x?

Comment: You should use Catalan numbers. The $n^{\text{th}}$ Catalan number gives the number of monotonic lattice paths from $(0, 0)$ to $(n, n)$ that do not pass above the diagonal. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number